# Why has Clang decided to allow designated initializers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, designated-initializer

I thought that designated initializers were discontinued in C++ and only worked in C. However, I came across a simple example which compiled and worked fine with clang++.

```
int main()
{
    int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
}
```

g++: https://rextester.com/AXIZ79197 (Error)

clang++: https://rextester.com/UYVHHP56966 (Works)

vc++: https://rextester.com/UCBEU10658 (Error)

Both g++ and vc++ failed to compile whereas clang++ worked just fine. It is also worth mentioning that g++ and vc++ gave different error messages. vc++ confused the designated initializers with lambda expressions. I guess I could blaim this on the fact that g++ is an older compiler, but I'm not sure tbh.

**Questions:**

1. Why has clang decided to allow designated initializers when g++ and vc++ didn't?
2. Is this just a compiler bug or is there another reason for this?

Comment: "Discontinued" is the wrong way to say it. C++ and C forked long before they were added to C.

Comment: @StoryTeller: No argument there. I just wasn't sure how to express it. Would "unsupported" be a better word?

Comment: Compilers are allowed to introduce language extensions. Seems that clang implemented this, while the others didn't.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos - I think so. But it's not worth an edit on its own. I'm just nitpicking :)

Comment: Same story as VLA from C.

Comment: Which `-std` version are you using?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Aren't VLAs supported in C++? I think VLAs are valid C++ code.

Comment: @taskinoor: Any. I think rextester uses -std=c++14

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos No, VLAs are not C++. Most compilers do support them, but it's not valid per standard.

Comment: And they are never going to be, that's why there is `vector`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Didn't know that. I always thought that since they are supported by many compilers, they were valid. Never used it, but still, I thought it was valid.

Comment: You could use `-Wc99-extensions` to let clang warn you about that or `-pedantic`

Comment: @t.niese: Good point. It does give you a warning indeed saying that it's c99 feature. But I'm stil curious as to why it was allowed. Maybe it's just a marketing thing, who knows.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos maybe to make it less a problem to use c libraries in c++. Most of it should be detectable with the file extension and the `extern "C"`, but maybe it would still not that reliable. But I would have expected that it would be an opt-in and not an opt-out.

Comment: Compilers are tools written by people for people. So if an extension is useful, compilers will implement it at their discretion. It's up to developers to decide if they want to conform to the standard (so that their code can be compiled on other compilers), or if they they target a specific tool-chain and so use its extensions to do cool stuff.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that designated initializers are back in C++20.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When compiled with `-pedantic` these warnings are generated:

```
source_file.cpp:3:18: warning: designated initializers are a C99 feature [-Wc99-extensions]
    int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
                 ^~~~~~~~
source_file.cpp:3:28: warning: designated initializers are a C99 feature [-Wc99-extensions]
    int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
```

It is clear that `clang++` by default enables `c99-extensions`.

This is not a bug as compilers may choose to provide additional feature. `clang++` developers simply decided to keep it enabled. It is better to use `-pedantic` if we don't want those features.

Interestingly, while searching for related information I came upon [C++ Support in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) page where "Designated initializers" is listed as partially supported via extension for upcoming proposals:

> experimental support for some proposed features of the C++ standard following C++17, provisionally named C++2a

[This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0329r4.pdf) is the exact proposal for upcoming standard. So there might be designated initializers in future C++.

Comment: Is there a way to enable c99-extensions in g++ and vc++ to see if they would compile the code above?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos Sorry I'm not aware of any option in g++ or vc++ which can compile the code that you posted. May be someone else can help with that.