# Designated initializers for nested arrays throw compiler error contrary to cpp reference

Tags: c++

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization , the following is seemingly a valid way to initialize a nested array.

```
const int arr[2][2] = {
        {[1]=1,},
        {[0]=10, [1]=11,},
};
```

Instead, the above throws me the following compiler error:

```
sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
```

I'm using GNU compiler version 20210110. I get the same result with '-std=c++20' as I do with 'std=c++98', etc.

Are non-trivial designated initializers supported by other compilers? Is the reference page wrong? Am I confused?

Comment: you are linking C reference not C++ - they are different languages with different standards

Comment: Did you **read** the error message? "sorry, unimplemented" pretty much says it all.

Comment: Although not directly related to nested arrays, see this question about designated initializers. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54459635/2754510

Comment: The perfect use for the compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/xTMKM54vM, just scroll through the different compilers and check the result.